# Mean value of complex exponential with random argument

Tags: probability

I have found in some works this result:

Let $t_k, k=1,2,\ldots,K$ be the set of event times of a Poisson process within a time interval $[0,T]$. Then,

$$\langle e^{(j\omega t_k)}\rangle =\dfrac{2 \cdot \sin(\omega \cdot T/2)}{\omega\cdot T}$$

For example in:
http://www.stanford.edu/~rsasaki/EEAP248/chapter1.pdf
page 25 (1.105).

How can I get this identity?

Comment: The left side of your proposed equality depends on $k$, the right side doesn't. Are you missing a sum over $k$ maybe? Also, the link doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's the average of some sort.  Not entirely sure

Comment: @muzzlator : What the notation $\langle\cdots\cdots\rangle$ _means_ is "an average of some sort"---specifically a weighted average in which the weights are probabilities.

Comment: The number $K$ itself is a random variable with a Poisson distribution with expected value proportional to $T$.  The _conditional_ distribution of the event times given the value of $K$ is actually the distribution of the order statistics of a sample of size $K$ from a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,T]$.  I might try finding the conditional expected value given $K$, then taking the expected value of that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Correct me, please, If I am wrong: the joint density distribution of the event times is given by the distribution of the order statistics of a sample of K i.i.d. Uniform([0, T]) random variables...$t_k$ is uniformly distributed within [0,T], so I can make $\langle e^{j\omega t_k}\rangle=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T e^{j\omega t_k}dt_k$

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's the _conditional_ distribution _given_ $K$.

Comment: The conditional distribution given K of the time event $t_k$ ( equals to $1/T$, for t in [0,T]), isnt it correct?

Comment: No.  The conditional distribution of $k$ event times in $[0,T]$, given that that's how many there are, is the distribution of the order statistics from an i.i.d. sample from a distribution whose density is $1/T$ on that interval.  That means each one has a Beta distribution.  The smallest one, for example, has a Beta distribution with parameters $1$ and $k$.  The expected value of the smallest one is therefore $1/(k+1)$.  The expected value of the second-smallest one is $2/(k+1)$, etc.